# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type

Tags: asp.net-web-api

error is

> ""Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
>
> "ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Expression`1[]' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",
> "ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>
> "StackTrace":" at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

my code:

```
public class ParticipantEventController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IParticipantEventRepository repository;


    public ParticipantEventController()
    {
        repository = new ParticipantEventRepository();
    }

    [Route("api/EventDetails/{EventId}")]
    [HttpGet]
     public IEnumerable<EventDTO> GetEventDetails(Guid EventId, params Expression<Func<Event, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
      IEnumerable<Event> participantevent = repository.FindbyEvent(EventId,x=>x.Id,x=>x.Contents,x=>x.EventRegisteration).ToList();
      var eventdb = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EventDTO>>(participantevent);
      return eventdb;

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to implement your custom `MediaTypeFormatter` that can serialize/deserialize objects of type `Expression<Func<Event, object>>[]`. No formatter are specifed by default in webapi's media type formatters list that can do this operation. Also when you send some data over the wire, you're required to set the `Content-Type` HTTP header value so that the server can be aware of it's processing capability on that type.

Comment: For more information , see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters